# VS compiles correctly but command line doesn't

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I have a project (.NET Core targeting .NET 4.6.1) that has lots of libraries in it. When I build the project from Visual Studio all assemblies are created correctly.

But when I delete the `bin` and `obj` folders and try to rebuild from PowerShell with `dotnet publish`, one of the libraries' assembly gets created badly; it's only half the file size and it doesn't work when I run the functionalities of that library.

The problem exist because I need to publish it through Team City so I can't do it from Visual Studio.

Anybody got any idea why it's behaving like this?

Comment: Run power shell as admin & then try command

Comment: I tried, unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you provide more information? What do you mean by "it doesn't work when I run the functionalities of that library"? My guess is that a lot of this could be due to which configuration you're using, but it can only be a guess without a concrete example. Could you clone your project and then gradually remove bits until you've got a [mcve]? That would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: When you say ".netcore targeting .net 461", do you mean you're using the new, lean `csproj` file while targetting full framework?

Comment: An assembly being half it's normal size sounds weird. But there are a few things that come to mind: Are you telling the commandline which platform and configuration to build? Is Visual Studio configured to pass any Defined Constants to the build?